# Copy the output of a TFS Build to a TFS Location

Tags: tfs, build

In TFS 11 a new feature has been added that allows you to specify a TFS location as a build drop rather than a network share. (see: http://blogs.blackmarble.co.uk/blogs/rfennell/post/2012/03/13/Dropping-build-output-to-source-control-in-TFS11.aspx)

Does anyone know of a way something similar can be achieved in TFS2010 through windows workflow or something similar.  I've spent several days searching and haven't been able to find anything useful.

The closest I've got is to run a custom powershell script that performs a check-in, but that does not seem to be working either.

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a few custom actions that use the TFS Version Control Client API to make the changes in the workspace and commit them. Ewald Hofman has a blog post that does a similar thing after updating the version number of a set of files.

http://www.ewaldhofman.nl/post/2010/05/13/Customize-Team-Build-2010-e28093-Part-5-Increase-AssemblyVersion.aspx

Should you create such custom activity, consider sharing it with the community [via the Team Build Extensions project](http://tfsbuildextensions.codeplex.com/).

Answer (score 0):

The simple dirty solution is to use few Invoke Process Activities to call xcopy, tf add and tf checkin commands and delete directory activity to get this done.